# jQuery: delete certain parts of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, foreach

I have a td containing a list of values (anchor tags) that are separated with a comma.

Is there any way I can create a button to delete specific values out of this string, e.g. the 1st or 2nd or 3rd value ?

I first tried to resolve this with a tagsmanager plugin but all the tagsmanagers I know only work with text but not with links / anchor tags so the above is meant as a work-around here.

The background is that I have a page that shows a list of uploaded files as links (created with PHP) and I would like to allow the users to be able to delete one or more of these links if no longer needed. The value of all links is the word File and a number, e.g. File 1, File 2, File 3 etc.

**Example td:**

```
<td>
<a href="link1" target="_blank">File 1</a>,<a href="link2" target="_blank">File 2</a>,<a href="link3" target="_blank">File 3</a>,<a href="link4" target="_blank">File 4</a>,<a href="link5" target="_blank">File 5</a>
</td>
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect in a number of ways. This one might be useful if you want to have a separate button to delete each link.

Just place a `button` after each link and assign the `click` event to something like:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('a').remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/6uXZC/)

Comment: I am going with this solution - thanks very much for the help !

Answer (score 2):

You can set the td to have an ID like `<td id="myID">` and then you can very easily select the nth-child of that td with jQuery:

```
var index = 4; // or whatever you want it to be
$("#myID a:nth-child(" + index + ")").remove();
```

If you don't want to set the ID of the td, you can of course select it another way, for example using

```
$("td:nth-child(" + tdNum + ")" ); // for the td
$("td:nth-child(" + tdNum + ") a:nth-child(" + linkNum + ")" ); // for the links
```

Comment: Works on IE 7,8 and 9. (Tested it at an online emulator, don't know for sure)

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest solution would be to wrap the items (and commas) in `<span>` tags:

```
<span class="file1"><a href="link1" target="_blank">File 1</a>,</span>
<span class="file2"><a href="link2" target="_blank">File 2</a>,</span>
<span class="file3"><a href="link3" target="_blank">File 3</a>,</span>
<span class="file4"><a href="link4" target="_blank">File 4</a>,</span>
<span class="file5"><a href="link5" target="_blank">File 5</a></span>
```

Then you can simply use jQuery to remove the whole `span`:

```
$('.file1').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make the links look like clickable tags, which when clicked will remove themselves.

```
<td>
    <a href="link1" target="_blank">File 1</a>
    <a href="link2" target="_blank">File 2</a>
    <a href="link3" target="_blank">File 3</a>
    <a href="link4" target="_blank">File 4</a>
    <a href="link5" target="_blank">File 5</a>
</td>
```

Then use JavaScript to make the links "delete" on click

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){

    this.remove(); // remove the clicked "<a>" tag

    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the link from going anywhere
})
```

Here is a **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgRg3/)**

And **[here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SgRg3/1/)** that allows you get more info about each clicked link so you could make a server-side request to remove the item